# Problem to run Amazon web service S3 integration code supported by Salesforce

Tags: soap, callout, amazon

I am using Salesforce supported sample code to integrate application with S3. I followed  this Link to install package
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Installing_Force_for_Amazon_Web_Services 
https://login.salesforce.com/?
 startURL=%2Fpackaging%2FinstallPackage.apexp%3Fp0%3D04t30000000OjsZ

When I am trying to get content list from bucket and for some other flows, I am getting following error(But some other flows are working fine i.e. create/delete bucket...). Not sure that there is some issue in my development organization or in installed Amazon package. Please guide me.
 "Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Please re-send this request to the specified temporary endpoint. Continue to use the original request endpoint for future requests. faultcode=soapenv:Client.TemporaryRedirect faultactor="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the endpoints based on [the region you set up on your bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region). For example, if your bucket is in *Northern California*, you will have to:

1. Change (or add a new one) the *Remote Site URL* to: *https://**s3-us-west-1**.amazonaws.com*
2. Change lines *178* and *1407* of your **S3.cls** file from:

> 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/soap';

to

> 'https://**s3-us-west-1**.amazonaws.com/soap';

3. Be sure you have access to the bucket, your key and secret are up to date, you created an **AWS Credentials** record with them, and you changed the **AWSCredentialName** variable value to whatever your credential's record is named, as [explained here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Installing_Force_for_Amazon_Web_Services).

Answer (score 2):

I made the following changes for ‘endpoint’ in the file “S3.cls” and able to run application.

**Older Code:** 
public String endpoint_x = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/soap';

**Newer Code:** 
public String endpoint_x = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/soap';

Comment: for more details, follow this link (I have no sufficient reputation to use more than 2 links in my answer)[link](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/set-up-installation/amazon-s3---must-be-addressed-using-the-specified-endpoint)

Answer (score 2):

I did what Sanjay suggested, and changed the S3.cls class.  I replace line 178 and 1406 with:

'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/soap' instead of 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/soap'

But also, I needed to update the Remote Site Settings.  So for me, I had to change the URL of my S3 Remote Site to https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Then it worked.